# Electronのレンダラープロセスからプリロードに定義された変数を呼び出したい

Tags: javascript, electron

Electronのレンダラープロセスからプリロードに定義された変数を呼び出したいです。
Electronのバージョンはv19.0.4です。

公式ページの[チュートリアル](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model)にしたがって以下のコードを作成しました。

しかし`undefined`が表示されてしまいます。
どこに原因があるのでしょうか？

- main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    useContentSize: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
    },
  });

  mainWindow.loadFile("index.html");
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
};
```

- preload.js

```
const { contextBridge } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  desktop: true
})
```

- index.html

```
...
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
...
```

- renderer.js

```
console.log(window.myAPI)
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
HTMLのフレームを使用していたのが駄目だったみたいです。
（フレーム内から呼び出したjavascriptにはなぜか値を渡せない）